# Is statistics is the same as mathematical modeling or is it about sophisticated guessing of a pattern between the data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling

"Is statistics is the same as mathematical modeling" or "is statistics about sophisticated guessing of the relationships between the data" or "is it meant to create a pattern between the data"?

Which of these are true?

Comment: As far as I can see, none of those are really true, but with appropriate definitions, restriction of scope, and caveats, one might make some level of argument for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very reasonable argument could be made that all of the above true in various applications of statistics.